# MySQLdb TypeError: not all arguments converted

Tags: python, mysql-python

I have read other entries of the same error, and have attempted their solutions, but have had no luck with my code.

```
columns = ['city', 'state', 'zip', 'latitude', 'longitude']
placeholder = '?'
statement = """LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Path/To/My/File""" + table_name + """.csv'
INTO TABLE propertyData.property_""" + table_name + """
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES ({})""".format(', '.join(placeholder*len(columns)))
statement = statement % tuple(columns)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "importer.py", line 59, in <module>
import_db("site")
File "importer.py", line 46, in import_db
print statement % tuple_cols
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I have ran it on different CSV files that I have, and they are error free, but one file in particular is causing this issue. The format of the file is the exact same  as the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String formatting with the `%` operator requires you to use printf-style format strings (i.e. `%s`, not `?`). Therefore, if you want to interpolate the column names using the `%` operator, do this:

```
statement = """LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Path/To/My/File/{}.csv'
INTO TABLE propertyData.property_{}
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES ({})""".format(table_name, table_name,
                              ', '.join(["%s"] * len(columns)))
statement = statement % tuple(columns)
```